# Calling a c function in Haskell comparing to Python

Tags: python, haskell, ffi

In Python I can do this:

```
import ctypes
import ctypes.util

my_lib = ctypes.cdll.LoadLibrary (ctypes.util.find_library ('my_lib') or 'my_lib32')
a = my_lib.some_function(33)
b = my_lib.some_function2(33)
c = my_lib.SOME_CONST_123
```

And since I need to convert this type of Python code to Haskell, I wonder can I do the same thing in Haskell? I know I can something like this throug FFI.
But it's not exactly what I can do in Python because as far as I am concerned in Haskell I'd have to declare the functions first like the following:

```
foreign import ccall "my_lib.h some_function"
     some_function :: CDouble -> CDouble
```

Is that true, is there an easier way?

Comment: There are tools to help generate bindings, e.g. c2hs. Are you aware of them?

Comment: @DanielWagner, not yet. Suppose I take a c library, will those tools generate the binding for all the functions from the library even if I don't know exactly what functions the library exports?

Comment: @Grienders Not likely. You'll want some degree of control over what functions get exported - e.g. only functions exported in certain headers. You'll also likely want to - in case of names_like_these - or _have to_ - in cases of NamesLikeThese - change the names of some functions, so completely automatic probably isn't the way to go. Most of the time it's not too difficult to write a script that extracts the relevant bindings for you though. ([language-c](http://hackage.haskell.org/package/language-c-0.3.2) may help with that if you want to do it all in haskell)).

Answer (score 4):

The ctypes library in Python is basically a wrapper around the C library `libffi` which is a library that let's us invoke arbitrary functions in the process's address space given information at runtime instead of compile-time.

The [same library](http://hackage.haskell.org/package/libffi-0.1/docs/Foreign-LibFFI.html) can be used in Haskell together with the dynamic linker to achieve the same effect:

```
import Foreign.LibFFI
import System.Posix.DynamicLinker

example :: IO ()
example = do
  dlopen "mylib.so" [RTLD_LAZY]
  fn  <- dlsym Default "some_function"
  fn2 <- dlsym Default "some_function2"
  a <- callFFI fn retCInt [argCInt 33]
  b <- callFFI fn2 retCInt [argCInt 33]
  return ()
```

This isn't ideal for a lot of reasons, and I wouldn't recommend building a large set of bindings like this for the same reason that many Python developers frown on using ctypes for bindings except as a last resort. For one it will have some overhead (roughly the same overhead that ctypes has) for each function call. As compared to a `ccall unsafe` FFI function from Haskell which [has basically no overhead](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/14519905/how-much-does-it-cost-for-haskell-ffi-to-go-into-c-and-back/14528162#14528162) and is as cheap as a native C function call.

Second, instead of having arguments with nice simple Haskell types like `Int` and `Float` arguments to functions are now all in a giant libffi sum type `Arg` that's opaque to the type system and is quite easy to introduce subtle bugs.

If you can link the C library at compile-time and forward declare the functions, either using the regular Haskell FFI ( `-XForeignFunctionInterface` ) and/or tools like c2hs it will make life much easier.